# Freezing the last layer of a neural network in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning

I am building a LSTM model with 6 input features and 2 layers each containing 128 neurons and finally 1 output neuron.Now I want to freeze the last layer. Here is the screen shot of the parameters and I want to know if the coding part

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

freezes the last layer or not!

I am attaching a screenshot for your reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnznf.png)

Is my process correct or not?

Comment: do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

No, your process is not correct. That will freeze all your parameters, not just the parameters on the last layer.

For more information on how to freeze only some layers, take a look at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-the-pytorch-freeze-network-in-some-layers-only-the-rest-of-the-training/7088/6